# Centering text vertically within a display:flex

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a calendar mobile webapp in which I am using jQuery Mobile Grid. Within any Cell there is another grid which might contain up to three different blocks representing a schedule. In order for these blocks to expand to the whole parent cell I use the display:flex property.

But I need to print some info within these blocks, and am struggling when it comes to centering the text vertically in each block. Since height is not specified directly, every method I have tried to center the text fails.

Basically this is what I have:

```
<div class="ui-grid-d">
     <div class="ui-block-a">
            <div class="ui-bar dia-block">
                <span class="dia_titulo"> 1</span>
                <div class="ui-grid-a turno-grid-container">

                        <div class="ui-block-a turno-block manana">M</div>
                             <div class="ui-block-a turno-block manana">T</div>
                             <div class="ui-block-a turno-block manana">N</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     ....
</div>
```

CSS: (turno-block should be the one centering the text)
    .turno-grid-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100%;

```
}

.turno-grid-container>div {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.turno-block {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% !important;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing my problem (text "M", "T" and such should be centered, not the day number): http://jsfiddle.net/kelmer/36xkggvc/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.turno-grid-container>div {
   flex: 1;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center; <-- add this
   display: flex; <-- add this
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/36xkggvc/6/